# Event Viewer Error with Event ID 3: WebHost failed to process a request repeating continuously

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, central-administration, sharepoint-farm

Below is the error details. Please suggest the solution for same.

This is on SharePoint 2016 Environment configure on Windows Server R2

> Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/62476613
>    Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/6ad627e30629460596e2cc21a0917c57/ProfileDBCacheService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The farm is unavailable.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The farm is unavailable.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPSecurityTokenServiceManager.get_Local()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceHostOperations.Configure(ServiceHostBase serviceHost, SPServiceAuthenticationMode authenticationMode)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileDBCacheServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>    Process Name: w3wp
>    Process ID: 5072

Comment: https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/9357/sharepoint-2016-forgets-where-its-installed-after-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution works for me. In my case the the issue is regarding User Profile so I have make those changes for respective Application Pool.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0187402-bfa1-4d48-b4ea-9ad52e659ca3/webhost-failed-to-process-a-request?forum=sharepointdevelopment